# Unable to create surface with bsurface addon

Tags: add-on

I'm using **bsurface addon.**

With the curve circle I have made some shape.
And add a  normal plane

I click on the curve and then shift selected the plane and press tab to go in edit mode
Then I click on add surface and I'm getting this error

**All splines must be bezier**

Im unable to create the surface.Any solution [image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think it's meant to be used this way. Could you add a link/quote to the documentation or the tutorial talking about this feature? I think that "add surface" is expecting to use object's grease pencil strokes. Never seen using another object (a curve) directly for feeding the operator.

Comment: @Carlo this is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvjQzKMaG-0                  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i39NKUJ3GeM

Comment: Thanks, never heard of this, I've learnt something new! Well, then you just have to convert your curve to bezier type (now they are poly), and it should works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Set Bezier spline type for your curves.

As the warning is saying, you need to work with "**bezier**" spline type. They are currently "poly" type (probably because you created the curves from mesh conversion, and by default poly is the choosen type).

Select all the curves and click the button you can find in the tool shelf under the Curve Tools section. A menu will pop up letting you choose the spline type for the selected curves.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply did u get what i get the output from it